# How to convert hex regisrty key to string with proper format with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, hex, registry, dword

I have some hex dword value which represents a software version is 33685504 but the actual version is 2.2.0.422 so what is the format to change that hex value to this with c#?

Comment: Is `33685504` the value in hexadecimal (base 16) or decimal (base 10)?

Comment: Its a hex value that i only know u can get it from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\  click on any subkey and see the version info

Comment: Is there any way please help me any answer will be appreciated

Comment: This might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks great help for me i should take DisplayVersion instead of Version from the registry